# Как изменить внутренние стили виджета Disqus

Tags: html, css, disqus

На сайте стоит виджет комментирования сервиса Disqus. Мне нужно изменить стили заголовков в разделе "Также на site.com".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заголовки "Охрана труда" и "Путёвка Озеро Яровое".
HTML разметка:

```
<header class="discovery-post-header">
<h3 title="Охрана труда"><span data-role="discovery-thread-title" class="title line-truncate" data-line-truncate="2">Охрана труда</span></h3>
<ul class="meta">
    <li class="comments">1 комментарий </li>
    <li class="time">2 месяца назад</li>
</ul>
```

CSS свойства:

```
.discovery-post h3 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: block;
  max-height: 2.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Никак не получается перехватить этот класс и изменить его свойство.

Answer (score 0):

```
.discovery-post-header h3 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: block;
  max-height: 2.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Возможно, нужно будет прибегнуть к !important, это сделает ваш стиль важнее оригинала.

Это только в вопросе опечатка, или -header не было в названии класса?

Comment: header нет в названии класса.
important также не помогает, так как disqus загружается как отдельный frame

Comment: Если он загружается как фрейм, то переопределить стиль не выйдет. (Разные домены)